# How do I make mediaelement.js prompt to download Flash?

Tags: mediaelement.js

If mediaelement.js can't load the Flash plugin, it just shows "Download File". How can I make it show a prompt to download the Flash plugin instead?

Is there some event it raises when Flash is not available?

Answer (score 1):

You can override what is displayed when no plugin is available by supplying a html snippet to `customError` property when you specify the media element options.

Here's an example:

```
$('#player').mediaelementplayer({
            customError:'Please install <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer" target="_blank">Flash Player</a> to listen to this file'
        });
```

If you're using the default skins, the text will probably be black, so you'll want to include something like:

```
<style>
        .me-cannotplay {
            color: white;
            font-size: 80%;
            margin: 5px;
        }
</style>
```